# Scrapy returns "None" as result some of the time but not all the time

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have created a Scrapy crawl spider with Rule objects and linkextractor to scrape Amazon bestsellers products but Scrapy sometimes returns None as result even though I know for sure that my xpath expressions are correct. It's so weird that Scrapy would return None occasionally instead of all the time. Here are my code for spider.py

```
class AmzcrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'amzcrawl'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/best-sellers-books-Amazon/zgbs/books/ref=zg_bs_unv_b_1_1_1/']


    rules = (
        #THIS RULE IS FOR THE FIRST PAGE OF BESTSELLERS
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//span[@class="zg_selected"]/../following-sibling::ul/li/a'), callback='parse_category', follow=True),

        # THIS RULE IS FOR THE SECOND PAGE OF BESTSELLERS
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//ul[@class="a-pagination"]/li[@class="a-last"]/a'), callback='parse_category', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_category(self, response):
        item = AmzbestsellerItem()
        item['dir_level_1'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//ul[@id="zg_browseRoot"]/ul/li[@class = "zg_browseUp"]/a/text())').get()
        item['dir_level_2'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//ul[@id="zg_browseRoot"]/ul/ul/li[@class = "zg_browseUp"]/a/text())').get()
        item['dir_level_3'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//ul[@id="zg_browseRoot"]/ul/ul/ul/li[@class = "zg_browseUp"]/a/text())').get()
        item['dir_level_4'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//ul[@id="zg_browseRoot"]/ul/ul/ul/ul/li[@class = "zg_browseUp"]/a/text())').get()
        item['dir_level_5'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//ul[@id="zg_browseRoot"]/ul/ul/ul/ul/ul/li[@class = "zg_browseUp"]/a/text())').get()

        #NAME OF CURRENT BESTSELLER CATEGORY PAGE
        item['category_name'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="zg_selected"]/text())').get()

        #URL OF CURRENT BESTSELLER CATEGORY PAGE
        item['category_url'] = response.url.split('/ref')[0]

        #THIS CODE IS FOR FOLLOWING INDIVIDUAL PRODUCT PAGE TO GET INFORMATION
        book_containers = response.xpath('//ol[@id="zg-ordered-list" and @class="a-ordered-list a-vertical"]/li')
        for book_dir in book_containers:
            book_dir = book_dir.xpath('./span[@class="a-list-item"]/div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative"]/span[@class="aok-inline-block zg-item"]/a[@class="a-link-normal"]/@href').get()
            book_url = response.urljoin(book_dir)
            item['book_url'] = book_url.split('/ref')[0]

            yield Request(book_url, callback=self.parse_book, meta={'item': item}, dont_filter=True)



    #GETTING INDIVIDUAL BOOK DETAIL. THIS IS WHERE PROBLEMS ARISE. I CANNOT GET ALL THE DETAILS EVEN THOUGH THE XPATH EXPRESSIONS ARE CORRECT
    def parse_book(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']

        item['book_referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None).decode('utf-8')
        item['title'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@id="productTitle"])').get()
        item['edition'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//h1[@id="title" and @class="a-spacing-none a-text-normal"]/span[@id = "productSubtitle" and @class = "a-size-large a-color-secondary"]/text())').get()
        item['author'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="author notFaded"]//a[@class="a-link-normal contributorNameID"]/text() | //span[@class="author notFaded"]/a[@class="a-link-normal"]/text())').getall()
        item['rating_num'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="averageCustomerReviews"]//span[@id="acrCustomerReviewText" and @class="a-size-base"]/text()').get()
        item['img_url'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="main-image-container"]//img/@src').get()
        item['publisher'] = response.xpath('//div[@id = "detailBullets_feature_div"]//span[contains(text(),"Publisher")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get()
        item['language'] = response.xpath('//div[@id = "detailBullets_feature_div"]//span[contains(text(),"Language")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get()
        item['isbn10'] = response.xpath('//div[@id = "detailBullets_feature_div"]//span[contains(text(),"ISBN-10")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get()
        item['isbn13'] = response.xpath('//div[@id = "detailBullets_feature_div"]//span[contains(text(),"ISBN-13")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get()
        item['asin'] = response.xpath('//div[@id = "detailBullets_feature_div"]//span[contains(text(),"ASIN")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get()
        item['kindle_price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-large mediaTab_title" and contains(text(),"Kindle")]/../following-sibling::div/span[@class="a-size-base mediaTab_subtitle"]/text()').get()
        item['etextbook_price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-large mediaTab_title" and contains(text(),"eTextbook")]/../following-sibling::div/span[@class="a-size-base mediaTab_subtitle"]/text()').get()
        item['paperback_price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-large mediaTab_title" and contains(text(),"Paperback")]/../following-sibling::div/span[@class="a-size-base mediaTab_subtitle"]/text()').get()
        item['hardcover_price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-large mediaTab_title" and contains(text(),"Hardcover")]/../following-sibling::div/span[@class="a-size-base mediaTab_subtitle"]/text()').get()
        item['spiral_price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-large mediaTab_title" and contains(text(),"Spiral-bound")]/../following-sibling::div/span[@class="a-size-base mediaTab_subtitle"]/text()').get()


        yield item
```

I'm not sure whether the problem is in my spider.py file or my pipelines.py file or not. Here is my pipelines.py file code:

```
class AmzbestsellerPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file, delimiter=";")
        self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['dir_level_1', 'dir_level_2', 'dir_level_3', 'dir_level_4', 'dir_level_5',\
                                          'category_name', 'category_url', 'cat_page_num', 'cat_referer', 'book_url',\
                                          'book_referer', 'title', 'edition', 'author', 'rating_num', 'img_url',\
                                          'publisher', 'language', 'isbn10', 'isbn13', 'asin', \
                                          'kindle_price', 'etextbook_price', 'paperback_price', 'hardcover_price', 'spiral_price']

        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

class DuplicatesPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter['book_url'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            #self.ids_seen.add(adapter['cat_page_num'])
            self.ids_seen.add(adapter['book_url'])
            return item
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tested your code and the error you seem to have is: 503 Unvailable Service. A classic error when scraping Amazon, the easiest solution is to use a USER_AGENT like `"Mozilla / 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 80.0.3987.163 Safari / 537.36"` and activate the cookies.

About the fields with None, remember to always use XPATH on the page source code, not on the already compiled page. In your case, many of the fields you query are not in the page source code and will therefore appear as None.

Comment: Thank you. How do I apply the XPATH to the page source instead of the compiled page?